# Compare date ranges with specific dates when building a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have been crushing my head on this problem for three days now maybe you can help me on this one.

So, I have 3 tables.

One called **Item Price** which contains the prices some items have for a given amount of time.

Basically the table looks like this:

```
ItemName | Startdate  | Enddate    | Price
-------------------------------------------
Watch    | 01/01/2012 | 04/08/2012 | 180€
Watch    | 05/08/2012 | 31/12/2012 | 150€
Watch    | 01/01/2013 | 31/12/2013 | 200€
```

The other table is named **Sales** which contains how many items have been sold during each month.

The table looks like this:

```
ItemName | SaleMonth  | Number
-----------------------------
Watch    | 01/01/2012 | 93
  .             .        .
  .             .        .
  .             .        .
Watch    | 01/05/2013 | 59
Watch    | 01/06/2013 | 74
```

And the last one called **Exchange Rate** with the exchange rate from Euros to Pounds for each Month.

```
ExchangeMonth | Rate  |
-----------------------
 01/01/2013   | 1.225 | 
 01/02/2013   | 1.166 |
```

To calculate how much I have gained during a month I use this formula:

```
Gain_month_i = (ItemPrice_month_i-1 * ItemsSold_month_i-1)/ExchangeRate_month_i
```

I want to calculate how much I've gained during a given period.

But I can't find a way to obtain the right result if the period I chose is overlapping on different periods in my Item Price table (e.g. if I want to see how much I've gained between the 01/02/2012 and the 01/01/2014)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of your problem is that your [Sales] numbers are aggregated by month, but the price of the item could have changed between the beginning and the end of the month. So, if you sold 50 watches in August 2012 you don't know for certain how many were sold when the price was 180, and how many were sold after the price dropped to 150.

It seems to me that the only reasonable solution would be to use an average monthly price based on the number of days during the month that the various prices were in effect. You could achieve that by using a VBA function like this:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function AverageMonthlyPrice(ItemName As String, AnyDayInMonth As Date) As Variant
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim FirstDayOfMonth As Date, LastDayOfMonth As Date, NumDaysInMonth As Long
Dim IntervalStart As Date, IntervalEnd As Date
Dim WeightedAveragePrice As Variant

WeightedAveragePrice = Null
FirstDayOfMonth = DateSerial(year(AnyDayInMonth), Month(AnyDayInMonth), 1)
LastDayOfMonth = DateAdd("d", -1, DateSerial(year(AnyDayInMonth), Month(AnyDayInMonth) + 1, 1))
NumDaysInMonth = DateDiff("d", FirstDayOfMonth, LastDayOfMonth) + 1
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "SELECT * FROM [Item Price] " & _
        "WHERE ItemName = [pItemName] " & _
            "AND Enddate >= [pFirstDay] AND Startdate <= [pLastDay]")
qdf!pItemName = ItemName
qdf!pFirstDay = FirstDayOfMonth
qdf!pLastDay = LastDayOfMonth
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
Do While Not rst.EOF
    IntervalStart = IIf(rst!StartDate < FirstDayOfMonth, FirstDayOfMonth, rst!StartDate)
    IntervalEnd = IIf(rst!EndDate > LastDayOfMonth, LastDayOfMonth, rst!EndDate)
    WeightedAveragePrice = Nz(WeightedAveragePrice, 0) + rst!Price * (DateDiff("d", IntervalStart, IntervalEnd) + 1) / NumDaysInMonth
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
If Not IsNull(WeightedAveragePrice) Then
    WeightedAveragePrice = CCur(WeightedAveragePrice)
End If
AverageMonthlyPrice = WeightedAveragePrice
End Function
```

So now you can run a query in Access that pulls together the quantity sold, the average price, and the exchange rate for each row in your [Sales] table:

```sql
SELECT
    Sales.ItemName,
    Sales.SaleMonth,
    Sales.Number,
    AverageMonthlyPrice(Sales.ItemName, Sales.SaleMonth) AS AveragePrice,
    [Exchange Rate].Rate AS ExchangeRate
FROM
    Sales
    INNER JOIN
    [Exchange Rate]
        ON [Exchange Rate].ExchangeMonth = Sales.SaleMonth
```

...returning something like:

```
ItemName  SaleMonth   Number  AveragePrice  ExchangeRate
--------  ----------  ------  ------------  ------------
Watch     2012-01-01      93  180                  1.225
Watch     2012-08-01      50  153.871              1.166
Watch     2013-06-01      74  200                  1.234
Watch     2013-05-01      59  200                  1.123
```

If you save that query in Access then you can use it (just like you would use a table) in other queries to perform the rest of your calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
If I understand well, this function will give the normal price if there are no price changes during the month or calculate the pro rata if it happens.
So if I want to execute my calculation with my formula I just have to do the following:
`SELECT SUM((AverageMonthlyPrice(Sales.ItemName, Sales.SaleMonth)*Sales.Number)/Exchangerate.Rate) AS Gain
FROM Sales, [Exchange rate]
WHERE Sales.Itemname="Watch" 
AND Sales.SaleMonth BETWEEN DATEADD("m", -1,01/02/2012) AND DATEADD("m", -1, 31/12/2013)
AND [Exchangerate].Exchangemonth = DATEADD("m", 1, Sales.SaleMonth);`
Am I right ?

Comment: @Tom Yes, the function should just give the "normal" price if there was no price change in that month. As for your query, why not give it a try against a small subset of your data and see if the results match what you get when you "do the math" yourself?

Comment: I marked it as good answer because I think this is the way I meant to do it but I have just one more question. This was just a simple example of what my problem was, my tables are a little bit more complex, for example Sales.Itemname isn't equal to [Item price].Itemname but the two tables are linked by another one. Which are the fields to modify in your function to match a table with different fields but basically the fields contain the same data ?

Comment: @Tom You may not have to change the function at all. The sample query at the end of my answer passes `Sales.ItemName` values to the function, but your query could just as easily pass it a value from some other table that maps `Sales.ItemName` values to `[Item Price].ItemName` values. (That mapping would presumably be achieved by doing a JOIN in the query.) In other words, the function does not know (or care) where its `ItemName` argument came from, it just has to be a string that will match the item names in the `[Item Price]` table.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I just add to make a few variable name changes in your code to match my tables.

Comment: Hi, Gord. I noticed something strange while doing various queries with your module. If I just have records for 1 year in my `[Item Price table]`, it return one price per month as wanted. But if I have records for 2012 and 2013 for example, it returns the good price but twice, for example I will have two rows with 01/01/2013 | 200€. The price displayed is the good one, but if I want to do a sum of results I will have twice the exact sum. I tested the query inside the code and it returns the expected values.

Comment: @Tom The VBA function is a *scalar function* meaning that it can only ever return a single (scalar) value. There must be something amiss with the JOINs in your query if you are seeing duplicate rows with the same date and price.